# Closing jframe from another jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 `jframes` `(jframeA,jframeB)`. On click of button in `jframeA` and `jframeB` must close.

`jframeA` is created at the start up of the project, below is the part of the code that creates the frame and sets it visible.

```
/*jFrameA*/
/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Login().setVisible(true);
    }
    });
}
```

(The above code is auto-created by netbeans)

I want to close this frame from `jframeB`. As we can see in the above code there is no object created of `jframeA`, only the constructor is called and set visibility to `true`. Since there is no object of `jframeA` I don't understand how to close this frame from `jframeB` on click of a button.

Please provide solution.

Comment: Please post the jframeB code also

Comment: jframeB is also created the same way as jframeA. In the method that  is executed on button click will contain the statement to close jframeA.

Comment: so where are you creating the jframe objects?

Comment: the jframe auto generated code only calls the constructor of classes that extends JFrame, as shown in the cose above.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Possibly use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 3) `new Login()` but then that suggests a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`..

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is no object of jframeA I don't understand how to close
>   this frame from jframeB on click of a button.

If you expect to act on an object, then you need to save a reference to it.

```
Login jframeA = new Login();
// ...
jframeA.setVisible(false);
jframeA.dispose();
jframeA = null;
```

Comment: I tried replacing the code mentioned in the question from jframeA with the code you mentioned, but the jframeA variable (in this case jframeA) is not accessible in jframeB.

Comment: jframeA and jFrameB both are in separate packages.

Answer (score 0):

First import the package of jframeB to jframeA. Write this code at the top of jframeA file.

```
import JFrameB; //write the name of the package of jframeB instead of "JFrameB"
```

Assuming the class name of jframeA is FrameA and the class name of jframeB is FrameB, I write below code.

```
FrameB jframeB = new FrameB();//write this code outside of all the methods but inside of the class.
```

You said that you use Netbeans. So double click on the button and write the below code inside of the ActionPerformed method.

```
jframeB.dispose();//this will close jframeB when you click on the button.
```

Comment: Changed the answer completely.